# Adding Authorization Header with Bearer Token in Swagger UI

Tags: jwt, asp.net-core-webapi, swagger-ui, swashbuckle, duende-identity-server

I'm trying to use Duende Identity Server and ASP.NET Core Web API with swagger. While trying to authorize the API with JWT Bearer Token, I can successfully authorize the API in swagger UI using bearer token (HTTP Security Schema https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/bearer-authentication/).
However, after authorisation, I can't see the authorization header with token passing with any endpoints. Still getting unauthorized calls. Here is the code I used, please guide me on what I'm missing.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.Authority = idServerSettings?.Authority ?? string.Empty;
        options.Audience = "API_1"; //APIResource Name
        options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidTypes = new[] { "at+jwt" };
    });

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    options.AddPolicy("ApiScope", policy =>
    {
        policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
        policy.RequireClaim("scope", "api_1");
    })
); 

builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.AddSecurityDefinition("HTTP_Authorization", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
        Scheme = "bearer",
        BearerFormat = "JWT",
        In = ParameterLocation.Header
    });
    options.OperationFilter<SwaggerAuthorizeCheckFilter>();
});

public class SwaggerAuthorizeCheckFilter : IOperationFilter
    {
        public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
        {
            operation.Security = new List<OpenApiSecurityRequirement>
            {
                new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
                {
                    [
                        new OpenApiSecurityScheme {
                            Reference = new OpenApiReference
                            {
                                Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                                Id = "bearerAuth"
                            }
                        }
                    ] = new string[] { }
                }
            };
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you post your entire program.cs class inclusve all the .UseXXXX statements?

Comment: If you replace the `Id = "bearerAuth"` line with `Id = "HTTP_Authorization"`, does it resolve the issue? (The security scheme _names_ used in `.AddSecurityDefinition` and `OpenApiSecurityRequirement` must match.)

Comment: Thank Helen, You are right. I have updated the same name for both, and now it working good.